# Are the video calls made in a 3G/4G network encrypted end-to-end?

Tags: encryption, end-to-end-encryption, video

When I make a video call through a cellular GSM/4G network, is there any end-to-end encryption? If yes, what kind of algorithms and CPUs are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Cell phone use encryption from the terminal to the base station, but there is no end to end encryption in 3G/4G. This would go against the ability to perform legal interception that is a requirements for telcos in most countries.

Comment: There are major differences between 3G/4G/5G in regard encryption & authentication. This answer is a bit sketchy.

Comment: I didn't speak about 5G on purpose, since I had no time to review 5G. The  only exception for 3G/4G that I can think off would be LTE D2D ProSe which would have permitted two terminals in range of each other to establish a direct channel bypassing the base station, but I don't think it made it to actual implementation.